# In woo commerce how to get order details using consumer id and product id?

Tags: woocommerce

i am getting user details by wp_get_current_user(); funtion .

By using of consumer id and product id how to know whether consumer purchase this product or not?

I tried this function also

```
 woocommerce_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **woocommerce_customer_bought_product** is now listed in deprecated functions of WooCommerce. You can check [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_customer_bought_product.html#245-250) link for the same.

Instead of using the deprecated function you can use **wc_customer_bought_product** function to achieve the same. Refer [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_bought_product.html#210-262) link for the new function to use.

wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id );

In WooCommerce Version which tested the deprecated function it works so there might be issue in the parameters sent. Just check the parameters. This function only return true if the product order status is **completed**.

Comment: Thank, but i used wc_customer_bought_product function also. Data not returning wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id ).I am calling this function outside of product page